# How to get Sales Order Item Name,Quantity, Rate from Purchase Order using Saved Search

Tags: javascript, search, netsuite, suitescript, purchase-order

**I want to retrieve the drop-ship /special order Purchase Record details along with associated sales order details using the saved search.**

The Saved search has to display the following columns:
1.Sales Order Date
2.Sales Order Number(Document Number)
3.Purchase Order Date
4.Purchase Order Number(Document Number)
5.Sales Order Item (Assembly Item)
6.Sales Order Quantity
7.Sales Order Item Rate
8.Sales Order Amount
7.Purchase Order Item(Component / Member Item).

I has created an saved search and displayed following values:
1.SO Date,SO #, PO Date,PO #, PO Item(Member Item),PO Qty.

**My Issue:**

When try to display the SO Item,SO Qty,SO Item Rate it is displaying the Item in the Purchase Order itself. i.e. showing same item(member item) in the purchase order instead of sales order item(assembly item).

For Getting  SO Item Lines Values , I have used the condition **"Applied To Transaction Fields"** it showing same item name in the PO.

And also I has tried the **"Created From Fields"** condition  , it showing empty values

**My Code:**

**Saved Search : SuiteScript 2.0 version**

```
var purchaseorderSearchObj = search.create({
    type: "purchaseorder",
    filters: [
        ["type", "anyof", "PurchOrd"],
        "AND", ["appliedtotransaction.type", "anyof", "SalesOrd"]
    ],
    columns: [
        search.createColumn({
            name: "trandate",
            sort: search.Sort.DESC,
            label: "PO Date"
        }),
        search.createColumn({
            name: "datecreated",
            join: "appliedToTransaction",
            label: "SO Date"
        }),
        search.createColumn({
            name: "tranid",
            label: "PO #"
        }),
        search.createColumn({
            name: "tranid",
            join: "appliedToTransaction",
            label: "SO #"
        }),
        search.createColumn({
            name: "item",
            join: "appliedToTransaction",
            label: "SO Item"
        }),
        search.createColumn({
            name: "quantity",
            join: "appliedToTransaction",
            label: "SO Qty"
        }),
        search.createColumn({
            name: "porate",
            join: "appliedToTransaction",
            label: "SO Item Rate"
        }),
        search.createColumn({
            name: "formulacurrency",
            formula: "{appliedtotransaction.quantity} * {appliedtotransaction.porate}",
            label: "SO Amount"
        }),
        search.createColumn({
            name: "item",
            label: "PO Item"
        }),
        search.createColumn({
            name: "quantity",
            label: "PO Qty"
        }),
        search.createColumn({
            name: "rate",
            label: "PO Item Rate"
        }),
        search.createColumn({
            name: "formulacurrency",
            formula: "{rate} * {quantity}",
            label: "Amount"
        }),
    ]
});
var searchResultCount = purchaseorderSearchObj.runPaged().count;
log.debug("searchResultCount:", searchResultCount);


//Retrieving values from the search result

purchaseorderSearchObj.run().each(function(result) {
    var soDateValue = result.getValue({ //Sales Order:Date
        name: "datecreated",
        join: "appliedToTransaction"
    });
    var poDateValue = result.getValue({ //Purchse Order: Date
        name: "trandate"
    });

    var soNumberValue = result.getValue({ //Sales Order: Document Number
        name: "tranid",
        join: "appliedToTransaction"
    });

    var poNumberValue = result.getValue({ //Purchse Order: Document Number
        name: "tranid",
    });


    var itemValue = result.getText({ // Purchse Order: Item
        name: "item",
    });

    var qtyValue = result.getValue({ // Purchse Order: Quantity
        name: "quantity",
    });

    var soItem = result.getText({ //Sales Order: Item
        name: "item",
        join: "appliedToTransaction"
    });

    var soQty = result.getValue({ //Sales Order:Quantity
        name: "quantity",
        join: "appliedToTransaction"
    });

    var soRate = result.getValue({ //Sales Order: Rate
        name: "porate",
        join: "appliedToTransaction"
    });

    var soAmount = result.getValue({ //Sales Order: 
        name: "formulacurrency",
        formula: "{appliedtotransaction.quantity} * {appliedtotransaction.porate}"
    });
    return true;
});
```

Is there any other way to retrieve the Sales Order Item  Lines Values (Assembly Item) from the Purchase Order.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you actually retrieving these values from the results? Also, I believe `createdfrom` is the appropriate `join`, but since you already tried that I may be wrong.

Comment: Hi Erictgrubaugh,I have updated the saved search code with how I'm retrieving values from the search result . Basically I tried to retrieve results drop-ship PO details by creating search on purchase order record and getting associated sales order values by the join (Applied to Transaction). I can able to get values such as Sales Order Date,Sales Order Document number etc, but can't able to retrieve item vales.Wondering why item values show same as in the PO instead of SO item values. Thanks.